# Arrow in CSS line-height different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an arrow made with `::before` and `::after` elements.
The problem is that it is used inside an element where font-size is calculated with line-height like so `font: 17px/1.2em zantroke;`

And what happening is that in Chrome it looks fine, but in Firefox the line is a little bit lower and the arrow looks bad.

Playing around with the styles I figured out that the problem is line-height which is somehow different in Chrome and Firefox. (possibly combined with font-family)

I tried to make an example as close to real thing as possible.

Arrow HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right"></div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.container {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
.arrow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;

    &::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    }

    &::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      top: 2px;
      right: 8px;
      background-color: orange;
    }

    &--left::before {
        left: 10px;
        border-right: 0;
        border-top: 0;
    }
    &--right::before {
        right: 10px;
        border-left: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px;
    }
}

.arrow:hover:before {
  border-color: black;
}
.arrow:hover:after {
  background: #000;
}
```

You can open this link in Chrome, Firefox and see the difference.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rujhqony/3/)

The question is how can I fix it? I guess I can make `line-height: 0` but can it be fixed without touching text styles?

Comment: I believe it has to do with how the different browsers handle half-units. In Firefox, open up the dev tools and do some live editing of the .container's line-height. Use px instead of em. On even numbers you'll see it lines up, on odd numbers it's slightly off. Your starting value of 1.2em translates to 19px by default, which is an odd number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by different rounding behavior between the browsers in the calculation of the `top` of the `.arrow::after` element.

Either changing the `height` of the `.arrow` from `5px` to `6px`, or removing the height completely and changing the `top` of the `.arrow::after` from `2px` to `-1px` seems to make things more consistent, and they look ok in my browsers.

Things also look a bit cleaner to me after changing the `left` and `right` properties of `.arrow--left::before` and `.arrow--right::before` from `10px` to `8px`.

```css
.container {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 2em;
}
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 35px;
}
.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  top: -1px;
  right: 8px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.arrow--left::before {
  left: 8px;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.arrow--right::before {
  right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
.arrow:hover:before {
  border-color: black;
}
.arrow:hover:after {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow arrow--left"></div>
  <div class="arrow arrow--right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ended up making `height` of arrow `6px` and it works. Thank you very much.